# How To Convert .bit file to .bin

Tags: fpga, xilinx, zynq, xsdk

I am following a tutorial on how to program the PL at run time for my ZedBoard. [Tutorial Here](https://www.hackster.io/anujvaishnav20/programming-the-pl-at-runtime-with-petalinux-72a820).

But I am stuck on the step where it says to `Convert.bit into.bin`.
From my understanding the difference between the two file types is that a bitstream contains a header.

Is there a command I can use to convert this, is there something in the XSDK that I can do to generate it from start up, or is there a way to manually strip the header file and rename it as a .bin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are some of the options:

- Once you have generated the bitsteam (.bit file) from Vivado/Vitis, run the following command to get a boot image (.bin file): `bootgen -image boot.bif -o i boot.bin`
- Further, you can also run the following command to split the image to get the bitstream binary `bootgen -image boot.bif -split bin -w on -p xc7kxxxx -o i boot.bin`
- Else you can set that option in bitstream settings while using Vivado GUI.
- Or you can also try this [script](https://gitlab.com/Woeber/fpgabintobit/-/blob/master/fpga-bit-to-bin.py).
- You can also check the official Xilinx video for [How to Convert Bitstream to Raw Binary Using BootGen](https://www.xilinx.com/video/soc/convert-bitstream-raw-binary-bootgen.html)

Comment: this seems to be how to convert a .bif to .bin rather than a .bit to .bin ... I don't seem to be able to use bootgen to read a .bit file.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a bitstream .bit into .bin, these steps worked for me (Zynq Ultrascale+ device):

1. Create a .bif file with the following content

```
the_ROM_image:
{
    [destination_device=pl] <your-path>/<your-bitstream-file>.bit
}
```

2. Use the bootgen tool provided by Xilinx to convert to a .bin file

```
bootgen -w -arch zynqmp -image convert.bif -process_bitstream bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Found [Bitstream Format](https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/18841847/Solution+ZynqMP+PL+Programming#SolutionZynqMPPLProgramming-BitstreamFormat) on the Xilinx Wiki which contains:

> From 2018.3 release onwards FPGA Manager supports loading of vivado and bootgen generated Bitstream and Bin files vivadobootgen[[1](https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx/commit/daca3d206a30e8b8238b97faac14d51cf2f5f35f#diff-b89be64e8f73a6802c4ba3b7af2e85aa)]
>
> Note: **For releases earlier to 2018.3 FPGA Manager was capable of loading only bootgen generated bin files.**

On the Wiki page there are examples of running `fpgautil` to load a `.bit` file.

I.e. if you are using 2018.3 release onwards think a conversion from `.bit` to `.bin` is no longer necessary. I haven't tested this with a Zynq device, but found it when looking for Xilinx documentation on the format of the header in a `.bit` file for writing my own Quad SPI configuration flash programmer for 7-series devices.